# Getting error in EMR (S3 bucket Access denied)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I am trying to read the data and write the output to the S3 bucket using Step function but unable to do. Getting Below error.

```
Status :FAILED
Reason : S3 Service Error.
Log File : s3://test-system/Log/EMR/j-27THIBBI6291N/steps/s-F9UPNCV45OHA/stderr.gz
Details : Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 0E94EA8E20FE8396), S3 Extended Request ID: 9QxTxb3bzNwPnIieC8UAAtnAcJp+Z4RgM+aqBSki7RjLW8pRHZiII30dU6Bm0qYAHrS2MQcE9r4=
JAR location : command-runner.jar
Main class : None
```

I have tried the same code in my Intellij and am able to read/write the data files from/to s3 bucket.

I have used Accesskey and Secrey key in my code and still am getting same error.
I am invoking jar file through lambda function in a Step function.

My code :

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3a://test-system/test.csv")
    sloggeri.debug("File Processing...","import_jar","sampleifleread","")
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")

    sloggeri.debug("File Processing...1....","import_jar","sampleifleread","")
    val res = spark.sql("select count(*) from data")
    sloggeri.debug("File Reading completed...","import_jar","sampleifleread","")

    res.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite")
      .save("s3a://test-system/Output/Test_Result")
```

above code is working and tested.
Could you please help me on this issue?

Many thanks.